# ADB install Failure erorr [-3001]

Tags: adb

Running the command given to me:

```
Adb install com.sec.android.app.camera_8.0.75-807500000_minAPI26(arm64-v8a)(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk
```

I get this error:

> 2255 KB/s (38144018 bytes in 16.518s)
> Failure [-3001]

What is this error? My device is an S7edge with Oreo without root.
Thanks.

Comment: I am voting for this to be closed. Not only is it off-topic, but it is very poorly written, beyond repair.

Answer (score 0):

What caused this error in my case was when I was installing a package via `myfiles` and I was update `myfiles` using `apodite` which in them middle of the package install `myfiles` was then installed as an unknown source the weird thing was that it only has problems with Samsung system apps.

I figured out a fix

```
adb shell pm install-create -i "com.android.vending" -r /sdcard/launcher.apk
```

Comment: I get this after I run your command: `Success: created install session [1618557884]` but the app doesn't appear.

Comment: Sorry about my timing. I'm a little late to the party. What app are you trying to install? Depending on the app it may not have a icon for the launcher. Also Remeber to +1 a good question and mark it as the correct anwser

Comment: @Shayan because this answer is wrong. I don't see how it is different from command `adb install <path/to/file>.apk`, but if you want to do it anyway, the first `adb push <path/to/file>.apk /data/local/tmp/` then `adb shell pm install-create -i "<packageName>" -r /data/local/tmp/<file>.apk` the you will get `Success: created install session [<session_id>]` then run `shell pm install-write <session_id> <name>.apk /data/local/tmp/<file>.apk` and then `adb shell pm install-commit <session_id>`